# Windows FOR loop won't set a variable properly

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a command procedure that will pick up the height of a video file and put that into the file name.  I've done a number of similar command procedures before, but this one is giving me a problem I've never seen before and which does not appear to be addressed in existing similar questions.

The basic command procedure seem reasonably simple.

```
@echo on

REM setlocal

REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b v*.mpg') DO (
 mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%%Height%% "%%G" > temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 set /p HeightVar=< temporary.txt 
 echo %HeightVar%
 REM RENAME "%%~nG" "%%~nG-%HeightVar%p%%~xG"
)


REM endlocal

REM setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

I'm testing this with a set of three files. The first one has a height of 684, the others are 720.  The command that runs mediainfo and puts the height value into a temporary file works.  I can look at the value and it changes for each file.  The rest of the commands seem to be o.k.  However, when I run the procedure I see this:

```
E:\Capture>set "HeightVar="

E:\Capture>set h
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\user001

E:\Capture>mediainfo.bat

E:\Capture>REM setlocal

E:\Capture>REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

E:\Capture>REM setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

E:\Capture>FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b v*.mpg') DO (
mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%Height% "%G"  1>temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 set /p HeightVar=  0<temporary.txt
 echo 720
 REM RENAME "%~nG" "%~nG-720p%~xG"
)

E:\Capture>(
mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%Height% "Variety_2024-02-08_1601_Pass1.mpg"  1>temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 set /p HeightVar=  0<temporary.txt
 echo 720
 REM RENAME "Variety_2024-02-08_1601_Pass1" "Variety_2024-02-08_1601_Pass1-720p.mpg"
)
684
720

E:\Capture>(
mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%Height% "Variety_2024-02-09_0000_Pass1.mpg"  1>temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 set /p HeightVar=  0<temporary.txt
 echo 720
 REM RENAME "Variety_2024-02-09_0000_Pass1" "Variety_2024-02-09_0000_Pass1-720p.mpg"
)
720
720

E:\Capture>(
mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%Height% "Variety_2024-02-09_1215_Pass1.mpg"  1>temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 set /p HeightVar=  0<temporary.txt
 echo 720
 REM RENAME "Variety_2024-02-09_1215_Pass1" "Variety_2024-02-09_1215_Pass1-720p.mpg"
)
720
720

E:\Capture>REM endlocal
```

I do not understand why the first "set /p HeightVar=< temporary.txt" picks up the wrong value.  You can see that temporary.txt contains the correct value, but when the procedure has been run the set command always uses the wrong value.

I have tried every combination of setlocal and endlocal I can think of (inside the loop and outside the loop"; I've tried turning delayed expansion on and off; I've tried every combination of both variables I can think of; I have cleared the value of HeightVar at the command prompt before running the procedure, as you can see from the output I have included here; and I can't get the loop to set the correct value for all of the files being read in the loop.

I'm willing to assume that there is some "simple" error that I'm overlooking, but for the life of me I can't find a combination that will work.  I have written a number of other procedures that go through directories finding files and processing the files or information about the files, including using MediaInfo, and this is the only one I've done that isn't working.

This is Windows 7 with all updates, if that matters.

At this point I'm willing to entertain any and all suggestions as to how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your question has major formatting problems making your question unanswerable in its current form.  Please take a moment and fix the formatting of your question. Specifically your code. Why are you not using something like PowerShell that’s easier to work with?

Comment: I very very very very strongly object to your comment that the formatting of the question is wrong, or that it's unanswerable.  When I look at it in my browser, everything is exactly as it appears in my Windows Command window and in Notepad when I edit the procedure.  I also think it's quite reasonable to use Windows Command file, and I don''t agree that PowerShell is easier.  All of the examples I have ever found for processing like this have been written in batch files, including all of the examples I have found here in this forum

Comment: If someone feels like re-writing the procedure in PowerShell, I would certainly welcome it.  In the meantime, I've done more experimentation and the problem appears to be that "set /p" does not immediately evaluate the result. I've tried to get an immediate evaluation with "!" instead of "%", but batch steadfastly refuses to evaluate the expression properly.  If some kind and helpful person could point me to how to expand on my examples so I can show you all how setting one variable to another uses the wrong value I will add that example to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around.  I gave up on trying to get set /p to work. There are several examples of a different way to read a value from a text file in this forum, and on the third article I read I finally found an example that actually works.  I adopted it for my procedure, and got this:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b v*.mpg') DO (
 mediainfo.exe --Inform=Video;%%Height%% "%%G" > temporary.txt
 type temporary.txt
 FOR /F "tokens=1" %%A in (temporary.txt) do (
    rename "%%G" "%%~nG_%%Ap%%~xG"
    )
)
```

It was important to have "tokens=1" and no "delim=" in the inside FOR loop.  I've tested it on three directories worth of files, and so far it works. However, some of the files I wanted to process have non-standard characters in them.  To get that to work I will have to add

chcp 65001

to the beginning of the batch process, and then

chcp 437

at the end.  The first one changes the code page so Windows will accept extended characters.  The second one resets back to the default code page.  If you don't reset to the default then commands like "more" will fail in that command window.

I was not able to find any explanation as to why "set /p" does not evaluate the way "set" does.

Comment: I have found a few files that don't process: when I use MediaInfo at the command line it finds the height and writes it to the temporary file properly: but in the FOR loop it writes a blank into the temporary file.  I don't yet know why that happens, MediaInfo should work the same way in both situations. But it did process almost 700 files properly so far, so it was worth the effort.